# Using output from curl post with IF ELSE statements

Tags: windows, api, batch-file, if-statement, curl

I want to run a bat file that checks the output of curl request and when the condition is met act accordingly.

the curl request in a bat file is as follows:

```
curl --insecure -X POST https://api.zilliqa.com/ -H "Content-type: application/json" --data "{\"id\":\"1\", \"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\", \"method\":\"GetNumTxBlocks\", \"params\":"[""]"}"
```

the output of the request is as follows: `{"id":"1","jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"5820"}`

and the the result is numeric, growing all the time. 
As complete newbie i can not figure out how to proceed. 
please give me advice, best if you could provide with example as well.

I want the IF statement to react when the last two digits of the result are greater than 95. is that also doable? for now the result is 4 digit number but will grow and be 5 then 6 digit number.

hope it is possible. if not, please suggest a possible solution.

Comment: Just want to make it clear to you that Stackoverflow is not a code request service. We are hear to help with any existing code you are trying to use to solve your problem. As it stands your question is off topic.  Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Please read, [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS curl.exe returns a json string like `{"id":"1","jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"5965"}`

You can parse with a for /f:

```
@Echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=4 delims=:}" %%A in (`
    curl --insecure -X POST https://api.zilliqa.com/ -H "Content-type: application/json" --data "{\"id\":\"1\", \"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\", \"method\":\"GetNumTxBlocks\", \"params\":"[""]"}"
`) do set "result=%%~A"
Echo result=%result%
```

To calculate the last two digits do a modulus division by 100 and compare with an if

```
Set /A "Last2Digits=result %% 100"
if %Last2Digits% gtr 95 (Echo greater 95) else ( echo less or equal 95)
```

Or do it in PowerShell:

```
$result = (curl.exe --% --insecure -X POST https://api.zilliqa.com/ -H "Content-type: application/json" --data "{\"id\":\"1\", \"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\", \"method\":\"GetNumTxBlocks\", \"params\":"[""]"}"|ConvertFrom-json).result
```

Comment: Thank you. it does not throw an error, BUT the result is not the actual number, but this: `result=result`

Comment: Sorry on copy and paste I missed a trailing perecent sign, changed.

Comment: thank you, it works like a charm. i will try to figure out the rest of my quest now.

Comment: See changed answer.

Comment: amazing. thank you for the lesson.